# could you tell me what this error means?

Tags: r

I just ran below R code but I am getting error msg... Could anyone help me how to make this code runable on my machine. Thanks.

Here's the command:

`load(file = "c:\\abcdeXXX.RData")`

And here's the resulting error message:

`Error in if (!grepl("RD[AX]2\n", magic)) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: My guess is your file is corrupt and is empty, i.e. the contents has length zero.  What is the file size in bytes, according to your OS?

Comment: It says 0 kb.. I think this is the reason..

Comment: OK, I have added an answer that explains this.

Comment: Just submitted a patch to R-devel substituting a more informative error message ... we'll see what happens.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you.  I made a mental note to figure out how to do that. You saved me the trouble.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect your file is empty.

The error message means that the argument `magic` has length zero.  If you read the source code for `load`, you will find the following line of code:

```
magic <- readChar(con, 5L, useBytes = TRUE)
```

Thus `magic` is the first 5 bytes of your file.  In other words, your file is empty.

Answer (score 3):

it is possible that the RData file you are trying to open is damaged or incomplete. Can you open it on another machine?

Also worth noting, early versions of R cannot open RData files created by later versions of R. Although I would not expect a version mismatch to cause your error.